# Error inserting into Oracle via parameters (Not all Variables bound)

Tags: c#, oracle, oledbcommand

As far as I can tell, all parameters are bound... Any ideas?  I've tried to find definitive answers, and tried adding these as parameters with explicit data types (the current code) and also just using the .addwithvalue (commented-out code).  Still getting the same errors.

```
        public bool WriteToDatabase(OracleConnection dbConnection, string sSiteCode)
    {
        if (!dbConnection.IsConnected)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not update record - connection closed!");
            return false;
        }

        //string sSQL = "select * FROM PSDATA." + m_sSiteCode + " WHERE PItimedate>'"+ m_sOracleStartTime +"' AND PItimedate<'"+ m_sOracleEndTime + "'  ORDER BY pitimedate desc";

        string sSQL_TO_UPDATE_RECORD = "INSERT INTO PSDATA." + sSiteCode + " (PITIMEDATE, PITIME, PIDATE, SRC, EVC, SEV, VSA1, VSA2, VSA3, VSA4, VSA5, VSA6, VSA7, VSA8, VSA9, VSA10, VSA11, VSA12, VSA13, VSA14) ";
        sSQL_TO_UPDATE_RECORD += " VALUES (:PITIMEDATE, :PITIME, :PIDATE, :SRC, :EVC, :SEV, :VSA1, :VSA2, :VSA3, :VSA4, :VSA5, :VSA6, :VSA7, :VSA8, :VSA9, :VSA10, :VSA11, :VSA12, :VSA13, :VSA14) ";

        //Set up the command
        OleDbCommand oCommand = new OleDbCommand(sSQL_TO_UPDATE_RECORD, dbConnection.ConnectionObject);
        oCommand.Connection = dbConnection.ConnectionObject;


        //Now add parameter values
        if (m_dtPIDateTime == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIMEDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) {Value = DBNull.Value}); } else {oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIMEDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) {Value =m_dtPIDateTime});};
        if (m_sPITime == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIME", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIME", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_sPITime }); };
        if (m_sPIDate == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PIDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PIDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) { Value = m_dtPIDate }); };

        if (m_SRC== null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":SRC", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":SRC", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_SRC }); };
        if (m_EVC== null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":EVC", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":EVC", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_EVC }); };
        if (m_SEV == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":SEV", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":SEV", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_SEV}); };

        if (m_VSA1== null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA1", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA1", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA1}); };
        if (m_VSA2== null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA2", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA2", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA2 }); };
        if (m_VSA3 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA3", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA3", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA3 }); };
        if (m_VSA4 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA4", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA4", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA4 }); };
        if (m_VSA5 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA5", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA5", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA5 }); };
        if (m_VSA6 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA6", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA6", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA6 }); };
        if (m_VSA7 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA7", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA7", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA7 }); };
        if (m_VSA8 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA8", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA8", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA8 }); };
        if (m_VSA9 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA9", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA9", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA9 }); };
        if (m_VSA10 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA10", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA10", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA10 }); };
        if (m_VSA11== null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA11", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA11", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA11 }); };
        if (m_VSA12 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA12", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA12", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA12 }); };
        if (m_VSA13 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA13", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA13", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA13 }); };
        if (m_VSA14 == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA14", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":VSA14", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_VSA14 }); };

        //oCommand.Prepare();
        /*
        if (m_dtPIDateTime == null) { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PITIMEDATE", DBNull.Value); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PITIMEDATE", m_dtPIDateTime.ToOADate()); };
        //if (m_dtPIDateTime == null) { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PITIMEDATE", DBNull.Value); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PITIMEDATE", DBNull.Value); };
        if (m_sPITime == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PITIME", DBNull.Value); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PITIME", m_sPITime); };
        if (m_sPIDate == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PIDATE", DBNull.Value); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":PIDATE", m_sPIDate); };
        if (m_SRC == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SRC", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SRC", m_SRC); };
        if (m_EVC == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":EVC", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":EVC", m_EVC); };
        if (m_SEV == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SEV", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SEV", m_SEV); };
        if (m_VSA1 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA1", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA1", m_VSA1); };
        if (m_VSA2 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA2", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA2", m_VSA2); };
        if (m_VSA3 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA3", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA3", m_VSA3); };
        if (m_VSA4 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA4", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA4", m_VSA4); };
        if (m_VSA5 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA5", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA5", m_VSA5); };
        if (m_VSA6 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA6", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA6", m_VSA6); };
        if (m_VSA7 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA7", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA7", m_VSA7); };
        if (m_VSA8 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA8", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA8", m_VSA8); };
        if (m_VSA9 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA9", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA9", m_VSA9); };
        if (m_VSA10 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA10", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA10", m_VSA10); };
        if (m_VSA11 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA11", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA11", m_VSA11); };
        if (m_VSA12 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA12", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA12", m_VSA12); };
        if (m_VSA13 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA13", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA13", m_VSA13); };
        if (m_VSA14 == "") { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA14", "."); } else { oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VSA14", m_VSA14); };
        */
        //Now execute the query
        Debug.WriteLine(oCommand.CommandText);
        foreach (OleDbParameter oParam in oCommand.Parameters)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(oParam.ParameterName + " " + oParam.Value.ToString());
        }
        //oCommand.Prepare();
        int nRowUpdated = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return (nRowUpdated == 1);

    }
```

Note that I commented-out oCommand.Prepare() as i apparently need to explicitly set the field length to use that!

Answer (score 0):

check below parameters

```
if (m_sPITime == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIME", OleDbType.Char) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIME", OleDbType.Char) { Value = m_sPITime }); };
if (m_sPIDate == null) { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PIDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) { Value = DBNull.Value }); } else { oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PIDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) { Value = m_dtPIDate }); };
```

1. if `m_sPITime` is `DateTime` then you need to change the type `OleDbType.Char`
2. Both conditions check same condition `(m_sPIDate == null)`, you may need to change the second as `if (m_dtPIDate == null)`

And also you can reduce if else statements by using `??` operator like below

```
 oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PIDATE", OleDbType.DBDate) { Value = m_dtPIDate?? DBNull.Value });
```

for string type

```
oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":PITIME", OleDbType.Char) { Value =(m_sPITime==null?(object)DBNull.Value:m_sPITime) });
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't solve my problem.  I managed to solve it by changing the System.OLEDB Object for an System.Data.OracleClient one.  Re the ?? operator, I get an error that it can't compare a string to a null.  I thought strings were nullable?